# Foreground service not started from BroadcastReceiver after boot

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, foreground-service

I want to launch a foreground service. When I start the Service from my activity everything works fine. But when I start the service via a BroadcastReceiver at boot/startup the service is never startet.(Maybe it is running and gets destroyed right away. Anyway I cannot see the notification-icon)

My phone has android 10, minSdkVersion 26, compileSdkVersion 29.

This is my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application...>

    <service android:name="de.ggg.location.PositionIntervallService"
        android:enabled="true"></service>

    <receiver android:name="de.ggg.location.StartupRecevier">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

The StartupRecevier:

```
public class StartupRecevier extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PositionIntervallService.class);
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                context.startForegroundService(intent);
            } else {
                context.startService(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The PositionIntervallService:

```
public class PositionIntervallService extends Service {
     @Override
     public void onCreate() {
       startForeground(FOREGROUND_ID, buildForegroundNotification(chan));

       // important work here
     }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can replace:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    context.startForegroundService(intent);
} else {
    context.startService(intent);
}
```

with:

```
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, intent);
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
```

Comment: thank you. I added the line to my manifest, but the service is still not called.